# How to replace the part of the url parameter in url rewrite using mvc?

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

How can we change the part of the url parameter in url rewrite using mvc.
Ex: http://www.test.com/segment1/segment2 should be redirect to http://www.test.com/segment1/segmentnew/segment2

http://www.test.com/segment1/segment2 should be redirect to http://www.test.com/segment1/segmentnew/segment2/segment3

The first one is working fine. But 2nd link is not redirecting properly.

The rewrite url is below

```
 <rewrite>    
         <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
          <add key="/segment1/segment2/" value="/segment1/segmentnew/segment2/" />       

        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
      <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
              <match url="(.+)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{Redirects:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" /> 
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

Comment: http://www.test.com/segment1/segment2 is that a typo, or you are trying to redirect to two different links from same url ?

Comment: need to redirect 2 different links

Comment: Like `a to b  and c to d`   or  `a to b and a to c`